# How to validate array of objects in express validator

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

```
         text_settings_descriptions: {
    'en': { language_id: '5a3a13238481824b077b23ca', value: '' },
    'ar': { language_id: '600eca59ced1c8317d473b54', value: '' }
  }
```

this is my address array

```
 app.post(
  '/addresses',
  check('text_settings_descriptions.*.value'),
 
  (req, res) => {
    // Handle the request
  },
);
```

And I am using this validation it validates both language's value. But I want it validates only 'en' language value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure that the value inside `en` is *not* empty, you can use the following:

```
const {check, validationResult} = require('express-validator');

app.post(
    '/addresses',
    check('text_settings_descriptions.en.value').notEmpty(),
    (req, res) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        console.log(errors);
        // ... handle errors and request
    },
);
```

With above code if the `value` was an empty value, the follwoing will be logged to the console:

```
 {
  formatter: [Function: formatter],
  errors: [
    {
      value: '',
      msg: 'Invalid value',
      param: 'text_settings_descriptions.en.value',
      location: 'body'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thank u for the comment but it not working

Comment: I've updated my code, please check and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left, if this answer solved your issue.